# iOS: sorting widget

Tags: ios, widget

Please, does anyone know of a widget which behaves like the one named "Example: Sorting in two dimensions" at:
http://tool-man.org/examples/sorting.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a gridview, for example [GMGridView](https://github.com/gmoledina/GMGridView)
it has two dimensional sorting as the one you posted in your question